# How do I call module function which is having same name as class private function?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, module

I am understanding how puts internally  working , for that I have created a class `Object2` and Module `Kernel2`

This is what i have created ,

```
module Kernel2
    module Display
        def my_print(var)
            sprintf "%s", var
        end
    end
end
```

```
class Object2
    include ::Kernel2::Display
    private_class_method :my_print
    def self.my_print(ob)
        sprintf("%s",ob)
    end  
    obj=Object2.new   
    obj.my_print("hello")  #=> Here , I want to call module my_print 
end
```

I wanted `my_print` works  similar as `puts`  i.e  when calling as class method it will call `Object2`   `my_print` and when calling as Instance method it will call `kernel2`  `my_print`.

I wanted to call `kernel2`  module `my_print` from the `object2` class so that it won't call `object2` `my_print`.
How can I fix this problem ??

Comment: How is that supposed to work? You have `Object.new` instead of `Object2.new` and `obj.myprint` instead of `obj.my_print`. Please fix your typos and create a [mcve].

Comment: I have edited typos

Comment: Did you try to run your code? Because I get a `NameError` from `private_class_method`

Comment: That's the actual issue I am facing , how can  I  call `kernel2` module ` my_print` from the object2 class so that it won't call `object2`   `my_print `

Comment: `private_class_method` expects the method to exist, so you have to call it _after_ defining the class method, not before. Just move the `private_class_method` call below `def self.my_print ... end`.

Comment: 1) `including` Kernel2::Display makes `my_print` and instance method of `Object2` not a class instance method (that would be `extend`) 2) to call that method directly from `Kernel2::Display` you would need to make it a module method via either `self.my_print`  called as `Kernel2::Display.my_print('Blah')` (but won't be included or extended to `Object2`) or by adding `module_function :my_print` which essentially creates the ability to access this method in both contexts. e.g. can be called directly but will also be included or extended to `Object2`

Comment: All that being said the way you are doing it now an instance of `Object2` will always call `Kernel2::Display#my_print` because `Object2` includes `Kernel2::Display` and does not define a `my_print` instance method